# Exclude class from the_content / Display shortcode in page_content

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem that shortcodes are not working in my wordpress page, because the content is being called be:

```
<?php echo $page_content; ?>
```

Now, on the actual page, there is a class called "theslide" and the **page_content** posts everything excluding the class "theslide".

I either need a way to activate shortcodes on **page_content** in the fuctions.php file, or a need a way to exclude the class "theslide" from **the_content**.

Thanks in advance
Willem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods you can use.

## 1

Use do_shortcode on the output which will run any shortcodes.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( $page_content ); >
```

## 2

Apply the same filters that are used on the_content() which includes running shortcodes.

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $page_content ); ?>
```